# float ignores the numbers after the decimal in c

Tags: c

i am trying to find the area of a triangle using heron's [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puB2m.png) (i used u instead of s) whose edges are random and when the sum of the edges is an odd number, my float ignores the numbers after the decimal.

here's a part of my code:

```
srand(time(0));

    triangle_1.a = rand() % 50;
    triangle_1.b = rand() % 50;
    triangle_1.c = rand() % 50;
    
    do
    {
        triangle_1.a = rand() % 50;
        triangle_1.b = rand() % 50;
        triangle_1.c = rand() % 50;
    } 
    while (triangle_1.a + triangle_1.b <= triangle_1.c | triangle_1.a + triangle_1.c <= triangle_1.b | triangle_1.b + triangle_1.c <= triangle_1.a);

    float area, u;

    u = (triangle_1.a + triangle_1.b + triangle_1.c) / 2;

    area = sqrt(u * (u - triangle_1.a) * (u - triangle_1.b) * (u - triangle_1.c));

    printf("%d, %d, %d, %f, %f", triangle_1.a, triangle_1.b, triangle_1.c, u, area);
```

and here is the output:

38, 37, 36, 55.000000, 565.482117

since u is 55 instead of 55.5, area is also incorrect. any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: What types are `triangle_1.a`, `triangle_1.b`, and `triangle_1.c`? Are you doing integer division? That always truncates to an integer

Comment: @Kevin yes!! thank you for the suggested question